# Access to model variables

Tags: c++, cplex

I am using IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.0 Accademy Licence with c++ on Linux and I am trying to build my model.

I am implementing it in a class called MILP and I would like to use some member function of MILP to add variables, constraints and objective functions.

The problem is that when I create a variable in a function, I cannot access it in the scope where I called the function. Is there a way to do access variables? Does it work with IloNumVarArray and IloArray?

Here it is an exemple of such a function:

```
void MILP::allocate_charging_current_variables(IloModel mod){
// just setting parameters for the for loop after
unsigned n_p = problem_setting->get_n_periods();
unsigned m = problem_setting->get_n_vehicles();

IloEnv env = mod.getEnv();
for (unsigned p = 0; p < n_p; p++)
    i_var[p] = IloNumVarArray(env, m, 0, 100, ILOFLOAT);
i_var.end();
}
```

Comment: `mod` should probably be passed by `const&` unless you really mean to make a copy of it; C++ passes by-value unless told otherwise, so this call copies `mod` into the function

Answer (score 0):

Variables created within a function are only in scope within that function. They can't be accessed outside of it - this is intentional; and it is a feature of C++ as a language, regardless of CPlex (which I'm not familiar with).

If you want your a variable usable elsewhere, define it where you need it. If you want to use a function to obtain the value for that variable - return that value from the obtaining function instead of it making its return type `void`.

PS: In your code snippet, `i_var` does not seem to be defined anywhere.